# EAP 7: Ignore or exclude Dependencies from 3rd party liberies MANIFEST.MF

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

In our war we bundle some 3rd party libraries that contain the `Dependencies` entries in their **MANIFEST.MF** files. JBoss modules with such names exist, so JBoss adds them to the application dependency list which causes that these JBoss-provided modules are used.

As we bundle all the required libraries in the war (they're different versions than those provided by JBoss anyway) we want to use these instead. However we don't seem to be able to exclude those undesired dependencies in any easy way so that we wouldn't have to modify those 3rd party libraries. **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** would be great, but excluding those modules here doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there any way how to ignore the `Dependencies` entries in **MANIFEST.MF** files, or any other way how to force exclude those dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

On a module dependency you can define the imports element and filter with exclude and include the paths inside your module that you don't want to be 'seen'. Something like this should work:

```
<imports>
  <exclude-set>
    <path name="META-INF/services"/>
  </exclude-set>
</imports>
```

Comment: I tried this approach already and it doesn't have any effect. I verified that the config alone works by modifying the offending jars and removing those Dependencies from their manifest files. But it appears that the MANIFEST.MF Dependencies entries have higher priority than jboss-deployment-structure.xml so I can't override them any way.